# Include image in RSS feed Views display

Tags: views, feeds

I'm creating an RSS feed of a basic Blog using Views. This is being picked up by Facebook's Graffitti module. Everything works fine here, except that the image isn't being added to the RSS feed... I've incuded a screenshot of my views settings... I'm using a Style of RSS Feed and Row Style: Node (this is the only type allowed).

How can I get a link to the image into feed?!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSvDE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is a CCK field, make sure the correct formatter has been selected for the image field and it has not been excluded from the RSS display at `admin/content/node-type/YOUR-TYPE/display/rss`.

If it's an attached image, check that it is displayed as part of teaser (or full body) and that *Feed content* is set to teaser (or Full text) at `admin/content/rss-publishing`.